# AdMob ads not showing when using mobile data

Tags: android, admob, banner-ads

I was testing my Android app with AdMob Google ads. It's working fine when I am using WiFi connection but the ads are not showing when I switch to mobile data. Is there anything to be added somewhere to allow access or if I upload to PlayStore the ads will start showing for both mobile data and WiFi users?

manifest code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```